# Implementing IQueryable.Count

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I'm working on an IQueryable provider. In my IQueryProvider I have the following code:

```
public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
{
    var query = GetQueryText(expression);

    // Call the Web service and get the results.
    var items = myWebService.Select<TResult>(query);

    IQueryable<TResult> queryableItems = items.AsQueryable<TResult>();
    return (TResult)queryableItems;
}
```

GetQueryText does all the leg work and works out the query string for the expression tree. This is all working well, so Where, OrderBy and Take are sorted. The webservice supports a count query using the following:

```
int count = myWebService.Count(query);
```

But I can't get my head round where I put this in the IQueryable or IQueryProvider.

I've basically worked from reading tutorials and open source examples, but can't seem to find one that does Count.

Comment: Uhm, it's returned from [IQueryable.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx).  What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm writing a provider, but I don't really know what I'm doing! I'm looking for examples really...

Comment: I'm impresssed you could implement `Where`, `OrderBy`, and `Take` if you don't really know what you're doing.  `Count` is exactly analogous to the others, so I'm puzzled by your confusion.

Comment: I suppose its because myWebService.Select always returns a List<TResult> (which is fine for where, orderby and Take) whereas myWebService.Count returns an int. I guess I need to understand the fundamentals more!

Comment: Here's a series of articles on an (admittedly rather complicated) implementation of IQueryable that does Count(). Count itself is in "Part X - Group By and Aggregates". [LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider series](https://web.archive.org/web/20160228161503/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears simpler than I first thought. [This blog post](http://developercontainer.blogspot.com/2009/08/linq-building-iqueryable-provider-part.html) helped:

> The Execute method is the entry point into your provider for actually executing query expressions. Having an explicit execute instead of just relying on IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() is important because it allows execution of expressions that do not necessarily yield sequences. For example, the query “myquery.Count()” returns a single integer. The expression tree for this query is a method call to the Count method that returns the integer. The Queryable.Count method (as well as the other aggregates and the like) use this method to execute the query ‘right now’.

I did some debugging and for a query of `myContext.Where(x => x.var1 > 5)` Execute is called and `TResult` is an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`

For `myContext.Where(x => x.var1 > 5).Count()` Execute is called and `TResult` is an `int`

So my Execute method just needs to return appropriately.